# Flow Currency Decimal Places being dropped when passed to Apex Class

Tags: apex, visual-workflow, action, decimal, apex-variable

My flow has a screen where the users enters a value in a currency field that has 2 decimal places and that value gets passed to a variable in an Apex Action within the flow.  For some reason, when I debug the flow, it shows it passing the decimal places (ex. $200.00) to the Apex, but once it gets passed to my Apex variable it is represented as only a whole number (200).

I'm using a Decimal variable in my method so I'm not sure why it is dropping the decimal points.

Do I need to specify the decimal points on the Decimal variable?  I would think that it would just carry over.

Here's my flow debug:

[image]

And Here's what is showing in my debug log for the Apex Action:

[image]

This is how I'm declaring my variable in the Apex:

```
public without sharing class chargentAPI_PartialRefund_Flow {
public class FlowInputs {
    @InvocableVariable public String transactionId;
    @InvocableVariable public Decimal refundAmount;
}
```

*EDIT to Add Screen shots of Error by 3rd party app:*

Approved:

[image]

Not Approved:

[image]

Here is the full code:

```
    public without sharing class chargentAPI_PartialRefund_Flow {
//Set the flow Input variables
public class FlowInputs {
    @InvocableVariable public String transactionId;
    @InvocableVariable public Decimal refundAmount;

    
}

@InvocableMethod
//Pass the input variables to the list
public static void issueRefund (List<FlowInputs> Request) {
    String transactionId = request[0].transactionId;
    Decimal refundAmount = request[0].refundAmount;
    
    //Add the variables to the callout
    callout(transactionId, refundAmount);
}

@future(callout = true)
//Pass the variables to the future callout
public static void callout(String transactionId, Decimal refundAmount) {
    
    //Generate the input data based on Chargent API documentation
    List<ChargentApiInput> createChargentApiInput = New List<ChargentApiInput>();
    ChargentApiInput gtwyData = new ChargentApiInput();
    gtwyData.ObjectId = transactionId;
    gtwyData.amount = refundAmount;
    createChargentApiInput.add(gtwyData);
    
    String jsonRefundData = JSON.serialize(gtwyData);
    System.debug('JSON Input: '+jsonRefundData);
    

        //Invocate refund click json method on Chargent API with json data as a parameter
        ChargentOrders.TChargentOperations.TChargentResult refundResult = ChargentOrders.TChargentOperations.RefundTransaction_ClickJSON(jsonRefundData);
        System.debug('Refund Result :'+refundResult.Message);
        
        
    String jsonString = refundResult.responseData;
        //GetResponse respsonse = (GetResponse) JSON.deserialize(jsonString, GetResponse.class);
       JSONParser parser = JSON.createParser(jsonString);
      parser.nextToken();
      parser.nextValue();
      ID recordId = parser.getIdValue();
       System.debug('Record Id' + recordId);
                  
        
       ChargentOrders__Transaction__c newTransaction = [SELECT Id, Main_Transaction__c FROM ChargentOrders__Transaction__c WHERE Id = :recordId];
       newTransaction.Main_Transaction__c = TransactionId;
        
       UPDATE newTransaction;
        
          
    
}

class ChargentApiInput{
    String ObjectId;
    Decimal Amount;
}
}
```

Comment: It's possible that this is just an artifact of how things are printed to debug logs. If you change your refund amount to be something other than a whole number (like `200.42`), do you still see the same result?

Comment: @DerekF you are right that when I put 299.99 it passes with the decimal as 299.99. But I need it to pass a whole number as 200.00 too otherwise it causes my 3rd party app to throw an error stating that 200 is not acceptable. The app still works, but I don't want this error to be logged.   Is there a way to check if the decimal places are being passed properly besides the debug logs?

Comment: Or is there a way to FORCE the decimal places to always be present?

Comment: [Decimal.setScale(2)](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_decimal.htm#apex_System_Decimal_setScale)?

Comment: Since the decimal places do appear for non-whole numbers, I'd be inclined to believe that there is no issue here. The fractional portion (.00) _should_ still be present (i.e. there shouldn't be anything that needs to be "forced"), Salesforce just isn't showing it in the log. Are you actually seeing your third party app returning a warning/error, or are you just trying to get ahead of a potential problem?

Comment: It's SHOWING an error, but appears to  pass through, but we're pushing to production for Monday and I'm afraid that when we get to a real credit card that the error will be a problem.  I'll edit my post to include screenshots of an approved transaction and on that is showing the error.

Comment: The error it show is **invalid amount parameter:200**

Comment: the issue is in how the apex code is generating the payload to the third party system.  Use [edit] and show how that is done

Comment: @cropredy I've added the full code for the class.  I believe the variable I'm passing for that value is also a decimal (see Decimal Amount declaration), but maybe it's then getting converted to String in the jsonRefundData to pass to the JSON method could that be where it is dropping the decimals?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the class

```
class ChargentApiInput{
  String ObjectId;
  Decimal Amount;
}
```

to:

```
class ChargentApiInput{
  String ObjectId;
  Decimal Amount;

  ChargentApiInput withObjectId(String val) {this.ObjectId = val; return this;}
  ChargentApiInput withAmount(Decimal val) {
      String s = String.valueOf(val.setScale(2));
      this.Amount = Decimal.valueOf(s);
      return this;
}
```

and then these lines:

```
ChargentApiInput gtwyData = new ChargentApiInput();
gtwyData.ObjectId = transactionId;
gtwyData.amount = refundAmount;
createChargentApiInput.add(gtwyData);
```

to:

```
ChargentApiInput gtwyData = new ChargentApiInput()
  .withObjectId(transactionId)
  .withAmount(refundAmount)
);
createChargentApiInput.add(gtwyData);
String jsonRefundData = JSON.serialize(gtwyData);
```

This anon apex was used to verify the approach:

```
Decimal d;
Decimal d2;
d = 200;
String s = String.valueOf(d.setScale(2));
d2 = Decimal.valueOf(s);
System.debug(JSON.serialize(d2));

prints: 200.00
```

Comment: Thank you for this! I can see in the log that converting to string at this point DOES retain the decimal points, but with this change, I'm now getting the error:  **Invalid conversion from runtime type String to Decimal**.

Comment: What line does the error occur on ?  If you do further operations on Amount and expect it to be decimal, you may need an intermediate someDecimal = Decimal.valueOf(xxx.Amount)

Comment: I believe it is occurring on Line 42 which is when we execute the apps refund method. I'm looking at the API documentation and it is saying that RefundTransaction_ClickJSON parameter of Amount is Decimal so could it be that it's trying to convert the String Amount I'm declaring back to a Decimal?  If that is the case is there any other way I can be sure the Decimal places are kept? This is Line 42           `ChargentOrders.TChargentOperations.TChargentResult refundResult = ChargentOrders.TChargentOperations.RefundTransaction_ClickJSON(jsonRefundData);`

Comment: you'll have to use [edit] and expose the method `ChargentOrders.TChargentOperations.RefundTransaction_ClickJSON`

Comment: unfortunately, I don't think I can do that because the method is part of a class in a managed package....so am I just stuck and will have to go back to the app provider?

Comment: no, you'll need to construct the JSON via technique other than JSON.serialize - use [JSONGenerator](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.234.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_json_jsongenerator.htm?q=json) which will allow you to construct a decimal via `writeNumberField`

Comment: actually, i have a better answer - see revised which skips the JSONGenerator

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132948/discussion-between-heather-and-cropredy).

Comment: Sorry, so what happens with this line directly below the last part of your edit? String jsonRefundData = JSON.serialize(gtwyData); I no longer have gtwayData....do I still use the JSON.serialize? or do I change it to JSON.serialize(createChargentApiInput)?

Comment: @cropredy, maybe I have overlooked something, but would `request[0].refundAmount = request[0].refundAmount.setScale(2)` not do (without String.valueOf())? And would it not have been simpler to use the variable names required by the JSON from the very start instead of having to reassign everything to a ChargentApiInput?

Comment: @FelixvanHove - I swear that I tried that and it didn't work but upon doing it again, your suggestion is fine and simpler.